# How to insert ordinal number into a listing?

Tags: listings, input-encodings

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}    

\title{DuvidaLatex}
\author{Ricardo Ramos}
\date{October 2017}

\begin{document}

 \begin{lstlisting}[caption={Testes de CRUD - Abordagem},label=testesgrupoA, language=Java]

    public class UniversidadesSystemTest{

        @Test
        @Carga(classe = UniversidadeCarga.class)
        public void adicionarUmaUniversidade() {
            UsuarioEm(AplicacaoPage.class).deve().acessarMenu("Universidades>Nova Universidade");
            UsuarioEm(IncluirUniversidadePage.class).deve().informarNome("Universidade Paulista").informarCidade("Sao Paulo - SP").informarEndereco("Rua Jardim Cris, nº 40, Santo Amaro")
                    .informarCEP("13572-000").salvar();
            UsuarioEm(ListarUniversidadesPage.class).deve().verificarQueUniversidadeComNomeECidade("Universidade Paulista", "Sao Paulo - SP").existe();
        }   

    }
    \end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

But when I compile my code the following message appears in the `nº40` character:

```
Package inputenc error: Unicode char \expandafter
Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Degree symbol**

This example shows the use of the **degree** symbol in the text and also in the **lstlisting** environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=0.5cm,right=0.5cm,headsep=15pt,footskip=27pt,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{listings}
%----------------------------------------
\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{inconsolata}
%-----
\usepackage{gensymb}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B0}{\degree}
%-----
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{azzul}{RGB}{6,96,167}
\definecolor{grverd}{rgb}{.133,.545,.133}
\definecolor{ruddy}{rgb}{1.0, 0.0,0.16}
\definecolor{gray(x11gray)}{rgb}{0.75,0.75, 0.75}
%-----
\lstdefinestyle{sycodjava}{%
    language=Java,
    showspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    breaklines=true,
    showstringspaces=false,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    commentstyle=\color{grverd},
    keywordstyle=\color{azzul},
    stringstyle=\color{ruddy},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    inputencoding=utf8/latin1,
    inputencoding=utf8,
    extendedchars=true,
    literate={á}{{\'a}}1 {ã}{{\~a}}1 {é}{{\'e}}1 {é}{{\'e}}1 {í}{{\'i}}1 {ó}{{\'o}}1 {ú}{{\'u}}1
    {Á}{{\'A}}1 {É}{{\'E}}1 {Í}{{\'I}}1 {Ó}{{\'O}}1 {Ú}{{\'U}}1%
    {°}{\textdegree}1,
    moredelim=[il][\textcolor{gray(x11gray)}]{$$},
    moredelim=[is][\textcolor{gray(x11gray)}]{\%\%}{\%\%}
    framexleftmargin=1mm,
    xleftmargin=2mm,
    numbers=none,
    columns=fullflexible,
    }
%----------------------------------------
\title{DuvidaLatex}
\author{Ricardo Ramos}
\date{October 2017}

\begin{document}
\section{Degree symbol}
Degree symbol in plain text still works: 90° is a right angle.

\begin{lstlisting}[style=sycodjava,caption={Testes de CRUD - Abordagem},label=testesgrupoA]
public class UniversidadesSystemTest{

    @Test
    @Carga(classe = UniversidadeCarga.class)
    public void adicionarUmaUniversidade() {
        UsuarioEm(AplicacaoPage.class).deve().acessarMenu("Universidades>Nova Universidade");
        UsuarioEm(IncluirUniversidadePage.class).deve().informarNome("Universidade Paulista").informarCidade("Sao Paulo - SP").informarEndereco("Rua Jardim Cris, n° 40, Santo Amaro")
                .informarCEP("13572-000").salvar();
        UsuarioEm(ListarUniversidadesPage.class).deve().verificarQueUniversidadeComNomeECidade("Universidade Paulista", "Sao Paulo - SP").existe();
    }
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

**Result:**
[image: Degree symbol in java code]

Answer (score 3):

If you are using UTF-8 extended characters in a listing, you must place within an escape to LaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listingsutf8}

\title{DuvidaLatex}
\author{Ricardo Ramos}
\date{October 2017}

\lstset{language=Java,
    label=testesgrupoA,
    caption={Testes de CRUD - Abordagem},
    escapeinside={\%*}{*)},
    breaklines=true,
    inputencoding=utf8,
    extendedchars=true
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
public class UniversidadesSystemTest{
    @Test
    @Carga(classe = UniversidadeCarga.class)
    public void adicionarUmaUniversidade() {
        UsuarioEm(AplicacaoPage.class).deve().acessarMenu("Universidades>Nova Universidade");
        UsuarioEm(IncluirUniversidadePage.class).deve().informarNome("Universidade Paulista").informarCidade("Sao Paulo - SP").informarEndereco("Rua Jardim Cris, %*nº*) 40, Santo Amaro")
                .informarCEP("13572-000").salvar();
        UsuarioEm(ListarUniversidadesPage.class).deve().verificarQueUniversidadeComNomeECidade("Universidade Paulista", "Sao Paulo - SP").existe();
    }   

}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Write the next code into the preamble:

```
\usepackage{textcomp}
\lstset{breaklines,literate={º}{{\hspace{-.2em}\scriptsize\textordmasculine}}1}
```